# Probability of obtaining at most one negative value in $5$ trials

Tags: probability

In an experiment, positive and negative values are equally likely to occur.  What is the probability of obtaining at most one negative value in five trials?

$$P(\text{obtaining at most one negative value in $5$ trials}) = \ ^5C_1 \cdot \left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \cdot \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^4 = \frac{5}{32}$$
But ans is  $\frac 6{32}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You calculated the probability of getting exactly one negative. It says "at most one", so you have to add in the probability of getting zero negatives, which is $1/32$. 
(also, your $36$s should be $32$s)